# Problem while Sending Binary Content to other Apps

Tags: android, android-fileprovider, android-intent-chooser

[image: manifest]I Just want to send the image which is there in my mobile to any android app, I have used this code which is not working. Showing Toast 'file is not supported' while trying to share to whatsapp.

```
share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            share_image();
        }
    });

private void share_image()
{
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+"/abc.jpg");
    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(Main2Activity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",file);
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP ) {
        shareIntent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION|Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION );
    }
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    shareIntent.setType("image/jpg");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<paths xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
 <external-path name="external_files" path="."/> 
</paths>
```

Comment: please show your AndroidManifest

Comment: <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>

Comment: please show your xml/provider_paths file

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>

Comment: Why don't you send only the path to the file? It's nothing but a string.

Comment: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading androidx.core.content.FileProvider uri content://com.example.demoshare.provider/external_files/Pictures/Title.jpg from pid=20344, uid=1000 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()

Comment: I'm getting this error.

Comment: add exported=true in the android manifest in the fileprovider tag